# Sql Datetime convert

Tags: sql, date

In a database table, I have two column storing date and time in this format:

```
   D30DAT   D30TIM
    140224  75700
```

I need update a new field where store date in the format

```
2014-02-24 07:57:00.000
```

How I can use a SQL query to do it?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: And what **datatype** are your columns?

Comment: With `D30TIM`, I see that `07:57:00` is represented as `75700`.  Do the minute elements always consist of two digits?  The hour component obviously doesn't

Comment: @MartinParkin - You'd really hope so, wouldn't you - since otherwise what time is `11300`? 13 minutes past one or 3 minutes past 11?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes indeed, this is what worries me!  I presume the values are stored in a numeric column, hence the leading 0 being dropped from the hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Postgres and Oracle (assuming those columns are varchar):

```
select to_timestamp(dt, 'yymmdd hh24miss')
from (
  select d30dat||' '||case when length(d30tim) = 5 then '0'||d30tim else d30tim end as dt
  from x
) t;
```

The `case` expression adds a leading `0` if the time part only consists of 5 digits so that the format mask can be specified with always 2 digits for the hour. The blank between the two columns is essentially only a debugging aid and could be left out.

The result is a *real* timestamp value that can easily be formatted using `to_char()` to the desired format.

SQLFiddle for Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac07a/2
SQLFiddle for Oracle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac07a2/4

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.  Its not particularly fast or great, but converts the fields you specified.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetDateTimeFromINT
(
    @Date INT,
    @Time INT
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @YearNo VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @MonthNo VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @DayNo VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @HourNo VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @MinNo VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @SecNo VARCHAR(2)

SET @YearNo = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Date), LEN(@Date)-4)
SET @MonthNo = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Date),LEN(@Date)-3,2)
SET @DayNo = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Date),LEN(@Date)-1,2)

SET @HourNo = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Time), LEN(@Time)-4) 
SET @MinNo = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Time),LEN(@Time)-3,2) 
SET @SecNo = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Time),LEN(@Time)-1,2) 

SET @YearNo = '20' + @YearNo
IF LEN(@HourNo) = 1 
BEGIN
    SET @HourNo = '0' + @HourNo
END

SET @MonthNo = CASE 
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '01' THEN  'JAN'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '02' THEN  'FEB'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '03' THEN  'MAR'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '04' THEN  'APR'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '05' THEN  'MAY'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '06' THEN  'JUN'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '07' THEN  'JUL'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '08' THEN  'AUG'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '09' THEN  'SEP'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '10' THEN  'OCT'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '11' THEN  'NOV'
                    WHEN @MonthNo = '12' THEN  'DEC'
                END

RETURN CONVERT(DATETIME, @DayNo + '-' + @MonthNo + '-' + @YearNo +' ' + @HourNo + ':' + @MinNo + ':' + @SecNo)
END
GO
```

Call it like so:

```
SELECT *, dbo.GetDateTimeFromINT(D30DAT,T30DAT) OutputDT
FROM SourceTable
```

If you need help with the update statement, let me know

Comment: Nice, but I would rather use the yyyy-MM-dd format for the date instead of using abbreviations of the month names as this may cause problems in other language settings. It also makes the function a little simpler. Still need an answer on the type of database that is being used though...

Answer (score 0):

Because someone gave a convoluted answer in SQL Server, I want to point out that there is a much simpler way.

I also want to point out that the format is not unreasonable.  It provides easy access to the date parts and it is sortable.  Of course, a real date/time value has these properties as well; I am guessing that this is some legacy format from some ancient system.

In any case, try this:

```
with t as (select 140224 as ymd, 75700 as hms)
select cast(cast(ymd as varchar(255)) + ' ' +
            stuff(stuff(right('000000' + cast(hms as varchar(255)), 6
                             ), 3, 0, ':'
                       ), 6, 0, ':')
from t;
```

This turns the numbers into the format `YYMMDD HH:MM:SS` which SQL Server recognizes as a date/time value.  Actually it would be better to pre-pend "20" for the four-digit year, but I'm not sure what the OP wants in terms of Y2K convertibility.

Although the code would look a bit different, similar logic would work in most databases.